# Copying the code from a webpage's iframe to the Java compiler at the time of program run

Tags: java

Is this even possible? I want to get the JAVA code exported from the website's URL (this code will be present in an iFrame of the website) and use it as a sort-of library file.

Comment: Hi, Raja Zuberi, an approach would be to post the Java code as Text to a server app, write the text to a file on disk and then executing then compile and run the code via command line;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what exactly you're asking/trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to get "some" data from a webpage. Check out jSoup, a library used to load and parse HTML webpages.